# How to send EGLD value to smart contract endpoint?

Tags: smartcontracts, multiversx

I have a smart contract method that looks like this:

```
#[payable("EGLD")]
#[endpoint(myEndpoint)]
fn my_endpoint(&self, #[payment_amount] payment: BigUint, some_value: u64) { ... }
```

And I call it with 5 EGLD value in transaction along with tx data

`myEndpoint@05@aa`

but tx result returns me `wrong number of arguments`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Payment args in EGLD are auto-filled from the call value you've already specified in the transaction, so you do not need to pass them as argument.

Therefore, your call data in this case would be `myEndpoint@aa`, without the payment arg.

As a side note, if this would've been an endpoint accepting another token than EGLD, you would've had to specify the token and amount in the data field, like:
`ESDTNFTTransfer@TokenIdentifier_in_hex@TokenNonce_in_hex@TokenValue_in_hex@Contract_address_in_hex@myEndpoint_in_hex@aa`.

The `ESDTNFTTransfer` function sends any type of ESDT token, with or without nonce. If the token doesn't have a nonce (fungible), you can either pass 00 as nonce or leave the nonce space empty, like `@TokenName_in_hex@@TokenValue_in_hex`.
Mind the fact that in order to use this function, you would have to compose a transaction with the destination set as yourself. The actual address of the destination would be contained in the data field in place of`Contract_address_in_hex`, making it a parameter of the `ESDTNFTTransfer` function.

If the endpoint accepted two tokens for example, then you could've used `MultiESDTNFTTransfer@Contract_address_in_hex@02@Token1Identifier_in_hex@Token1Nonce_in_hex@Token1Value_in_hex@Token2Identifier_in_hex@Token2Nonce_in_hex@Token2Value_in_hex@myEndpoint_in_hex`.

And yeah, you can always check the MultiversX docs on ESDT Tokens / NFT Tokens for more details.